# Weighting a data frame within another frame for map creation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, maplex

I've currently got an inset data frame sitting in a corner of a larger data frame. Some labels are being half covered by the smaller data frame. I was wondering if there are any tips on how to weight it (either in Maplex or Standard) so that the labels that are half covered are either removed, or moved so that they aren't behind the smaller data frame?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be slight overkill to deal with some overlapping labels but you could try the script mentioned in this [blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/01/28/data-driven-pages/). Step 4 discusses using a python script (available in the template download that accompanies the blog) that will move an inset map to the most suitable corner of your map.

Alternatively you could convert the labels to annotation and manually move or remove those that are covered by the inset map.

Comment: Thank you! This will work. I am working with data driven pages so this will definitely save me some time (compared to converting everything to anno and manually removing).